# NextJS - specifying tags and revalidate when fetching - what takes precedence?

Tags: next.js, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

`revalidateTag('mytag')` doesn't seem to work if I `fetch()` like this:

`const res = await fetch(url,  { next: { tags: ['mytag'], revalidate: 3600 } })`

I would expect it to revalidate even if the revalidate interval hasn't passed yet.

Right now I have to wait the full hour for the page to regenerate. Is this expected behaviour?